# Why DrawableCompat.setTint() method is not woking correct?

Tags: android, drawable, android-appcompat, tint

I have a question.
Why when i use

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

is not working, and when i use

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), R.color.white);
```

is working?

In documentation is like

```
public static void setTint(@NonNull Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int tint){}
```

so means i need to provide a resource, not an int.

Thank you.

Edit:

I see if my function is annotated with `@ColorInt`, `(..., @ColorInt int color)`, is working if i provide a color resource. Is getting more confusing. If is not, resource color is ignored.

Comment: `tint: Color to use for tinting this drawable`, so it needs a 32 bit long int color, not a resource id

Comment: Btw `@ColorInt` is the colour value whereas `@ColorRes` is the resource id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resolve the color before using it. `R.color.white` is just a pointer to the id in `R` file.

By invoking `getResources().getColor(R.color.white)` you resolve the color.